Inlay hints and completion not working for Rust through rust-analyzer
Problem
Inlay hints and autocompletion are not showing up while typing or moving the mouse pointer in Visual Studio Code for Rust code.
However, JavaScript inlay hints and autocompletion work, for instance.
Also note that Rust is working properly, and as such I do get diagnostics from cargo check in my IDE.
Expected behavior
Inlay hints and autocompletion working for Rust code.
Version
Visual Studio Code: 1.92.2
rustc version: rustc 1.83.0-nightly
Installation: Rustup x86_64-windows-msvc nightly
Windows: Windows 10 22H2
Extensions
"rust-analyzer" (0.3.2096)
Settings:
{
    "rust-analyzer.discoverProjectRunner": null,
    "rust-analyzer.linkedProjects": [],
    "rust-analyzer.restartServerOnConfigChange": true
}

Earlier versions
As to when it was working, I unfortunately do not remember the versions used of the above extension and Visual Studio Code for example. I just have gone back to Windows 10 without much backup.
RustRover
JetBrains RustRover just works when compared to Visual Studio Code, and I get inlay hints and autocomplete as desired.

Could you include any research you have done and things that you have tried in the question body please? Was it working before? If so, what changed on your system between it working and not working? What version(s) of VS Code are you running and which plugins are you using?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@music2myear I have no information about the earlier versions, though.

As in, you upgraded and then things stopped working? Or is it less distinct than that? Looking at the developer's pages have you found others reporting this issue?

@music2myear No luck searching for it...

Is Rust accessible through e.g. VSCode terminal? What are your settings for the extension?

@Destroy666 I've updated the question with these details, even though I omitted just one setting that had nothing do with the problem.
